# How to Animate the GridViewItem Image just like the Microsoft Groove Music

Tags: c#, uwp

I am developing a music player. In the Albums page, I show all the albums in a GridView. While panning, the image of the GridViewItem changes a bit later after reaching a certain position. It happens because of the virtualization and caching mode. I want to animate the opacity of the image while changing so that the user won't see the last image that was in that GridViewItem just like the Groove Music. How can I achieve that? Should I create or add DataTemplate programmatically while panning in the event called *ContainerContentChanging OR *ChoosingItemContainer ? Just give me a reference or hint.

Comment: Hello, can you provide some code or pictures to illustrate further your intentions? Regarding animation, you can check the [documentation on Storyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/storyboarded-animations)

Comment: I can. Wait, I give u.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MY1SMheCQJTToy1S_MqTbaasbw9ax9Cg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I want to animate the cover image just like groove music so that user cannot see the image changing.

Comment: This is my code

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XGlNexpDy1J8Ma9ZFmG0H1tnM-LZ-XKa/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

If you want a gradual effect when the image is loaded, there is a control ImageEx in WindowsCommunityToolkit that can help you.

- [ImageEx source code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/ImageEx)

You can directly reference the control. When `ImageEx.Source` changes, the state changes internally.

It creates a `Storyboard` to control the `Opacity` of the image from 0 to 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Hello, do you have any new progress? if you have other questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: ImageEx is like magic control. It also reduced the RAM size that my app used to consume a lot before using the ImageEx. Thanks a lot. Perfect solution. I am now interested to know how did it manage to reduce the RAM size.

Comment: `ImageEx` will cache the loaded pictures (this is more obvious when making network requests), it will load the cached pictures first, thereby reducing network requests and reducing RAM load

Comment: Wait. I have the source code of that sample. I will investigate that. By the way, You use my apps. 
https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9P2T0014P292

https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9PP3HBRZNVVW